# how do you display a certain aspect of an image without changing the dimentions of said image?

Tags: html, image, css, background

I have a header at the top of my page that is currently overlaying an image. the image is of a *paralympian* running and my webpage is about why amputees need to keep participating in sport.

I really want the image to show him running and of his prosthetic legs but when I insert the image it only shows the top half of him. I want to keep the image dimensions the same as they span across the whole page and look good but I basically just need the image to move upward without changing the dimensions.

```css
.image1 {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474014465286-9887839a5971?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=76a7a6bde1dd9e68d64b55ea5d907991) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <h1 class="headline"> how sport can help those suffering from lower-limb amputations </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: there you go, i added the code for you

Comment: Well if your Header has a very wide format, like 20:5 but your image is of a different format (for example 16:9) you can't fit the image into that header without any borders or cropping parts of the image.

Comment: @SamButch thanks, added my suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is `background-position` property - see a demo below where I have positioned it to the `center`:

```css
.image1 {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474014465286-9887839a5971?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=76a7a6bde1dd9e68d64b55ea5d907991) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <h1 class="headline"> how sport can help those suffering from lower-limb amputations </h1>
</div>
```

See this reference: [w3-shcools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/pr_background-position.asp)

You can specify `x` and `y` positions too using percentages / pixels - see demo below:

```css
.image1 {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474014465286-9887839a5971?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=76a7a6bde1dd9e68d64b55ea5d907991) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-position: 25% 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <h1 class="headline"> how sport can help those suffering from lower-limb amputations </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @SamButch let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: This helped so much!! the "background-position: 25% 25%" was perfect for choosing the bit i wanted! cant thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options here:

- simple one: using css bg position property e.g.
  `background-position-y: bottom;`
- put this div with `height: 100%;`    inside another div which will
  have same image with `width: 100%;` and    with blur applied (so your image will have full height and the rest of space will be covered with the same scaled and blurred image). you can
  use this reference for blurring
  http://thenewcode.com/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS
- use aspect ratio for header to maintain image proportions - here's
  the reference for this
  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/